# SVG Path: Interactive Editing of Bezier Curves

Tags: javascript, html, svg

**Examples** of what I'm looking to do:
[image]
[image]

I've been looking for a tool to manipulate a loaded svg path and [polygon](https://interactjs.io/) as I can use [Snap.svg Free Transform](https://github.com/ibrierley/Snap.svg.FreeTransform) for resizing and rotating.

Well I couldn't find a library besides [Paper.js](https://groups.google.com/g/paperjs/c/eQrFW3eP_eM) that allows me to have interactive editing of Bezier curves however I don't want to work with canvas at all JUST SVG and I couldn't find anything for the SVG element.

I'm still super confused as all I can find via Codepen and Github are demos in which the svg objects are inline HTML and the Javascript is targeting the inline HTML that wasn't dynamically added.

I know there are libraries like [Vector.js](https://vectorjs.org/), [Snap.svg](http://snapsvg.io/) or [SVG.js](https://svgjs.dev/docs/3.0/) that I maybe able to use. However while reading up on the API's I know [SVGGeometryElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGPathElement) has a method [getPointAtLength()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGGeometryElement/getPointAtLength) which returns the point at a given distance along the path.

My question is first is there a js library that allows me to have interactive editing of Bezier curves both fill and stroke? If so where and is there a demo to help me understand how to use it? If there isn't based upon what I want to do which is to to ONLY work with SVG what library of the 3 is the best and why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `getPointAtLength()` method is not useful for your needs. You need to be able to access a list of path commands and their parameters. But `getPointAtLength()` is not that.

SVG has an [old API for accessing path segments](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/paths.html#InterfaceSVGPathSeg). However this is deprecated now, because it was somewhat ugly and difficult to use.  I'm not sure which of the browsers, if any, still support it.

There is also a [new API that has been proposed](https://www.w3.org/TR/svg-paths/#InterfaceSVGPathSegment) in a new SVG Paths module.

I've lost track of which browsers have removed the old API, and which have implemented the new one.  You'll need to check.

If you want to be backward compatible, Philip Rogers has created [a polyfill library for the old API](https://github.com/progers/pathseg).

If you get desperate, there are other libraries for parsing path definitions that you could use.  For example: https://www.npmjs.com/package/svg-path-segments. *Note that this is not a recommendation. I have not used that library.*